# Does the bounty system not auto-award anymore?

Tags: support, reputation, bounty

According to the [What is a bounty? page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty),

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount. If there's no answer meeting those criteria, the bounty is not awarded to anyone.

I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22725280/bug-when-resizing-borderless-window-with-sdl2) the day after a bounty was set on it, and received the necessary 2 upvotes. However, even though the bounty has ended and the grace period has also ended, my reputation level has remained unchanged.

I had expected to get half the bounty, per the bounty rules I quoted. Does the bounty system not work that way anymore? Have the requirements changed for getting the auto-awarded 50%?

(P. S. This is my first experience with receiving a bounty, so I don't know if this is a SO-exclusive bug or something more general to SE. If this would be a better fit for [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/), please let me know and I'll delete it.)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The bounty hasn't actually ended yet.  If you look at the revision history there is no "bounty ended" note, and there is still a bounty banner on the question when viewing it.

Bounties aren't awarded the instant that they end.  There is a batch process that runs every so often and actually awards out the bounties.  If you look at the revision history of that same question, you'll see that there was a previous bounty, and it was ended about 7 days *and an hour and a half* after it was started.

Be patient.

Comment: Thanks. I was under the impression the bounty was given at the same time the "Grace period has ended" message showed up. I'll wait.

Comment: It would be good to add this information to the 'about bounties' page.

Comment: I have one question here, even though grace period ended, and i met the criteria for bounty ( answered after bounty started, got 2+ upvotes), i have not received half of bounty! please suggest how it works!