# Why didn't I receive half bounty?

Tags: discussion, bounty

I answered this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807120/generated-javadoc-pages-unneccesarily-wrap-method-arguments-with-annotations/32921528#32921528) with a score of 6 and the question had a bounty.

According to what I read in the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount. If two or more eligible answers have the same score (i.e., their scores are tied), the oldest answer is awarded the bounty. If there's no answer meeting those criteria, the bounty is not awarded to anyone.

I should have received half of the bounty now that the bounty and grace period is finished

> This question had a bounty worth +50 reputation from RAnders00 that ended yesterday. Grace period has ended

and considering that my question has enough up-votes. But the thing is that I didn't receive the expected +25 points.

Can anybody explain this situation? Is it maybe too soon for me to receive and I need to wait for a few more hours? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would go with the `too soon` option, but that's a blind shot...

Comment: Check [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250184/does-the-bounty-system-not-auto-award-anymore). You need to wait a while, as bounties are not awarded immediately.

Comment: You'll have to wait until the bounty is awarded.  The OP won't take care of it, he has left the building as usual.  A script needs to run to auto-award the bounty, that can easily take an hour or more after the grace period ended.

Comment: Yes. The banner is still there, so it isn't fully ended now. Just wait until the banner is gone.